# Drupal views UI, is it possible for the user to limit the number of row of the result?

Tags: views

I created a view that display some content. I would like to allow the user to change the number of result (row).

By example, the view display ten row. The user can set (in text field?) 5, and the view display only the first five result.

Is it possible via view ui ? I didn't find...
If not, I guess that I must create a custom module with view alter..

Thanks for help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Go To view .Set pager options and do the change given in above screen shot

Comment: I want the user can set this value =)
So, without use the view configuration page.

edit: my ask is ambigu, when I saided "via View UI", I meant "without use a custom module". Is there an option that add a text field for the user and allow him to set the limit of elements of the result ?

Comment: below this check Exposed options.Click on Expose items per page check box.Set options their that you want

Comment: Is not the number of item per page I want, but the total of element display by the view (without pagination). So, the result show 15 rows in the page, I want the user can set this value and, by example, he want show only the first 3 elemnts (without pager)

Comment: hmmm, indeed youre right ! I have the result I want with pager option. I find it weird I need use the pager option x) 
Thank you !

Comment: Yours welcome..

Comment: I dont know how to Set pager options ?? I cannot find that :(